# Change Parent control Button Text from User control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to change the Parent control button text from user control. I was able to find the control but the following code doesn't seem to work. Also I tried to hide but it doesn't seem to work. Please advise.

### User Control

```
 protected void combo1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
       if (Combo1.SelectedItem.Text == "Officer")
        {
                    Button saveBtn = (Button)this.Parent.FindControl("saveButton");
                    saveBtn.Text = "Forward";
                   //saveBtn.Visible = false;

        }
 }

Parent control button(.aspx page).
-----------------
   <asp:Button ID="saveButton" runat="server" Text="Save" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Comment: is the onchange event on combo1 a real postback or an ajax call?  if it is the latter you cant change anything since your webpage is not rendered again.

Comment: it's a real postback not ajax call.

Comment: I tried to add this code on page_load. It works fine. I am not sure why it's not working on selectedIndexChanged handler.         Button saveBtn = (Button)this.Parent.FindControl("saveButton");
                    saveBtn.Text = "Forward";

Comment: and you dont set the text attribute any where else?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50554/Callback-WebControls there is explanation of the envtorder of asp.net callback  might give you a hint

Comment: No. I didn't set up anywhere else.